# datepicker shifting max date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am currently setting jQuery datepicker settings in this way (it is supposed to be for picking birthday):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: 'c=101:c+1',
    minDate: '-100Y',
    maxDate: '0',
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
    });
```

But, a problem exists. When I go back to year 2002 for example and choose a day in August. And I try to reopen datepicker to select another date, the maximum year I can now choose is 2003??? What gives?

Thanks.

Comment: You are giving a year range of +1 relative to the current selected year. What did you think yearRange was doing?

Comment: Preferably I was hoping it was always relative to current time, but yes, what you say makes sense, I am asking too much.

Comment: It is relative to the current time if you drop the "c". [Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange)

Comment: Should of made it an answer, but thank you oh Calendar guru!

Comment: you can't do this as you need correct time & that can only be given by a serve so you need to use some server site language to get the correct date